# Показать блок после того как scroll оказался на нужном div'e

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день, помогите сделать с помощью JS всплывающий блок. Идея такая: Показать `fixed-element` после того как доскролили до `block2`. Пытался написать, но у меня не работает(

```js
let intro = document.getElementById('intro');
let fixed = document.querySelector('.fixed-element');
let introrSourceBottom = intro.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (intro.classList.contains('fixed') && window.pageYOffset < introrSourceBottom) {
    intro.classList.remove('fixed');
    fixed.classList.remove('fixed');
  } else if (window.pageYOffset > introrSourceBottom) {
    intro.classList.add('fixed');
    fixed.classList.add('fixed');
  }
};
```

```css
.block1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.fixed-element {
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: $orange;
  color: $white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}

.block2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: #000;
}

.fixed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">block 1</div>
<div id="intro" class="block2">
  <div class="fixed-element">
    fixed
  </div>
  <div className="intro-list">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у тебя fixed-element   и так находится в block2...  объясни, что ты хочешь?

Comment: хочу что-бы как мы доскролили до `block2` то `fixed-element` показался.

Answer (score 0):

Написал скрипт, кому будет интересно вот:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    let intro = window.document.getElementById("intro").offsetTop;
    let fixed = document.querySelector(".fixed-element");
    let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;

    if(scrolled > intro) {
        fixed.style = 'display: block';
    } else {
        fixed.style = 'display: none';
    }
};
```

```css
.block1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.fixed-element {
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}

.block2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: #000;
}

.fixed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">block 1</div>
<div id="intro" class="block2">
  <div class="fixed-element">
    fixed
  </div>
  <div className="intro-list">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```